# Image swap on hover with jQuery: No image after click and de-hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I implemented a jQuery swap-on-hover image function which goes like this:

```
// header image hover

var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
};

$(function () {
    $('img.logoswap').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

It does work perfectly as long as there is no click on the image (which is a link).

But: Once the image is being clicked **and** the mouse is being placed off the image (so within the seconds while the other page is loading), the image dissapears and only the alt tag is shown.

I wasn't able to recreate it in jsFiddle as they don't allow links within the frame, so here's the live example (removed because problem not visible anymore). The image hover link is the logo on the upper left. The code and markup being used can be seen in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psteinweber/z643C/1/), but as mentioned the error I'm talking about cannot.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? Like locking in the latest state or something?

Comment: Your live example looks to work fine with what you've described. Browser you're using? And any particular reason you aren't just doing this VERY EASILY with CSS?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in chrome, what browser are you using? Also have you tried using a css hover to swap out the image?

Comment: It can be seen by clicking the image and then hovering away. Latest Chrome, latest OSX. 
I'm not doing it via CSS background image, because it has a responsive image class assigned. But the same is probably possible with background size too. I guess I just wanted to improve my jQuery skills a bit :)

Comment: any reason you're just not using CSS for the hover?

Comment: also, since you're loading separate images, if your browser (for whatever reason) isn't caching anything, it might be attempting to retrieve the image from the server each and every time. This is one of the reasons why using sprites is a good idea.

Comment: Ok will go for a CSS solution. Thanks for the input!